Inject IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> in a constructor waiting for IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext>
I'm developing an Asp.Net Core Library intended for use across various microservices within my environment.
The primary goal of this library is to standardize the code used for database access. I've therefore created a BaseDbContext class that implements EntityFramework's DbContext class.
Subsequently, different developers and I are supposed to implement my BaseDbContext within our own ApplicationDbContext.
In our environment, we have multiple databases, say one per user.
For each user request, we need to find their specific database and then dynamically construct a DbContext.
To accomplish this, I am looking to register a DbContextFactory that will create an ApplicationDbContext for each request, fetching the corresponding ConnectionString through a method called RetrieveConnectionString.
So far, it's pretty straightforward and looks like this:
public static WebApplicationBuilder AddApplicationDbContextFactory<TApplicationDbContext>(this WebApplicationBuilder builder) where TApplicationDbContext : BaseDbContext
{
    builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<TApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureDbContextOptions(options);
    });
    return builder;
}

The ConfigureDbContextOptions method calls the previously mentioned RetrieveConnectionString.
My issue is that within the same library, I also have various classes that already use DbContext, such as Repository or an UnitOfWork.
The ApplicationDbContext does not exist when writing the library's code, so the code relies on the BaseDbContext class:
public class UnitOfWork(IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext> dbContextFactory) : IUnitOfWork
{
    protected bool _disposed;
    private readonly BaseDbContext _dbContext = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
}

My problem is that even though our future ApplicationDbContext classes implement the BaseDbContext, and I register IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>, when the Repository and UnitOfWork classes try to retrieve an instance of IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext>, I receive an error because I haven't registered IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext>.
I tried adding this to my method:
public static WebApplicationBuilder AddApplicationDbContextFactory<TApplicationDbContext>(this WebApplicationBuilder builder) where TApplicationDbContext : BaseDbContext
{
    builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<TApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureDbContextOptions(options);
    });

    builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext>), provider =>
    {
        return provider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<TApplicationDbContext>>();
    });

    return builder;
}

But I obviously get the following error:

'Object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextFactory[ApplicationDbContext]' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory[BaseDbContext]'.'

How can I make it so that my Repository and UnitOfWork can use a BaseDbContext when registering an ApplicationDbContext?
UPDATE 1 :
As pointed out in the comments, the error relates to conversion, not casting. It originates from a DAO which was implementing my Repository class.
I modified the code as follows:
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext>), provider =>
{
    return (IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext>)provider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<TApplicationDbContext>>();
});

Now, I encounter a casting error:

System.InvalidCastException : 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextFactory[ApplicationDbContext]' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory[BaseDbContext]'.'

This is somewhat surprising since the TContext parameter of IDbContextFactory<> is covariant.
Also, it might be worth noting that it's attempting to cast an Internal.DbContextFactory to an IDbContextFactory.

You don't need a UnitOfWork because the context itself is already a UoW. That being said, it seems that you should use UnitOfWork<TApplicationDbContext>.

I've added some logic to my UnitOfWork that differs from the original DbContext. I'd like to keep it that way.
I considered using a generic UnitOfWork, but since my Repository is already a generic class Repository<T>, I prefer to avoid overloading the generic parameters to maintain ease of use if possible.
Do you think there is any other solution?

I might be missing something about the "obviously" part of your error. IDbContextFactory<>'s TContext parameter is covariant, so it should be possible for any IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> to be cast as an IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext>. The language of that error says "converted" instead of "cast," though, which makes me think it's coming from reflection or dynamic expression trees or something. What's the stack trace for the error?

@StriplingWarrior interesting, I updated my question to add a few details

Double-check that ApplicationDbContext actually extends BaseDbContext. Maybe you've got the wrong namespace someplace so you're using a different type than you think you're using? What happens f you use the generic AddScoped signature? .AddScoped<IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext>>(p => p.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<TApplicationDbContext>>())

IDbContextFactory<TContext> is not covariant, you cannot cast IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> to IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext> even if ApplicationDbContext derives from BaseDbContext. To resolve this issue ypou can create an adapter class DbContextFactoryAdapter<TDerivedContext> that implements IDbContextFactory<BaseDbContext> and wraps an instance of IDbContextFactory<TDerivedContext>. Modify your DI registration to use this adapter, allowing services expecting a BaseDbContext factory to receive an adapted version of the specific context factory.

@JalpaPanchal thank you, this idea is working well ! If you can convert your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved

@M.Ozn why do you want any of this to begin with? A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection and doesn't need to be "abstracted".

@M.Ozn the adapter won't work either unless you specify the actual type, which makes the entire idea somewhat pointless. It's a very expensive way to cast ApplicationDbContext to BaseDbContext - only to cast back so you can use the Unit-of-Work's entities and execute queries

It seems the real problem is misunderstanding how EF Core works or what DbContext is. Even then, nothing prevents you from using generic classes and methods with the actual ApplicationDbContext as a type parameter, as long as you use a generic constraing where T:BaseDbContext.

@PanagiotisKanavos First of all, thank you for your response. This is not the first time I have read that a Repository around a DbContext is unnecessary. My former tech lead had this habit, and I never questioned it because I found the usage simpler and more elegant.
Following your response, I read other posts where you had explained why it was not needed. I also read several blogs you mentioned. You have convinced me, and I will remove the Repository and UnitOfWork classes.

@PanagiotisKanavos To answer your question about why I want a BaseDbContext, it is mainly for two reasons:

To enforce a schema (modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(Schema);)
To enforce a convention for dates (configurationBuilder.Properties<DateTimeOffset>().HaveConversion<DateTimeOffsetConverter>();).
I have taken note of using interceptors for SaveChanges and creation/modification dates that you mentioned in another post.


@PanagiotisKanavos If you know how I can avoid a BaseDbContext class by applying these conventions elsewhere, I would be glad to hear your suggestions. Ideally, I would like to manage with the base classes IDbContextFactory/DbContext/ApplicationDbContext.

IDbContextFactory is not covariant, you cannot cast IDbContextFactory to IDbContextFactory even if ApplicationDbContext derives from BaseDbContext.
To resolve this issue ypou can create an adapter class DbContextFactoryAdapter that implements IDbContextFactory and wraps an instance of IDbContextFactory. Modify your DI registration to use this adapter, allowing services expecting a BaseDbContext factory to receive an adapted version of the specific context factory.

That's effectively what IDbContextFactory does in the first place. This proposal (not answer) won't work if the actual type isn't known either. Neither IDbContextFactory nor .NET's Reflection can guess which of the multiple implementations of BaseDbContext to instantiate
